# Windows 8 javascript change the attribute of branding to name

Tags: javascript, windows

I have a windows 8 application updating tiles periodically. In the tile update i wish the logo to be replaced with the Application name.Did a analysis on the same and found the attribute value"branding" to be changed to name.But setAttribute method is throws "0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'setAttributes'"

Below is the code snippet placed in default.js

```
var squareTileXml = Notifications.TileUpdateManager.getTemplateContent(Notifications.TileTemplateType.tileSquareText04);
var tileattributenode = squareTileXml.getElementsByTagName("binding");
tileattributenode[0].setAttributes("branding","name");
```

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is!

Comment: I get the error.but how to rectify that?

Comment: Do you see anything different about the method name mentioned in the error message and the name of the method you typed as the second word of your last sentence in the question above?

Comment: I dont find any difference between the two.

Comment: You can't call a function that doesn't exist. There is no such function `setAttributes` on the `tileattributenode[0]` element, so it must be something else. The correct function is `setAttribute` (singular). Using IE's F12 Developer tools, Firefox's FireBug, or Chrome's console would help you debug these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct. Instead, try `setAttribute()` and see if you get farther.

Comment: Thanks for the reply williambq.Will try the suggestion